# Where do iPhone voice memos sync to on my Mac?

Tags: iphone, itunes, voice-memo

Is iTunes configured to sync voice memos from my iPhone? If so, where can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find Voice Memos in

```
/Users/yourname/Music/iTunes/Voice Memos
```